# Is it possible to change the structure of DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In Visual Studio WinForm application, I have a `DataGridView` control showing a lot of records from my database. Right now, it is showing all data in "Grids" like following:

```
[Name] [ID] [Age] [Group]
[Michael Jones] [1541441551] [20] [S]
[Emily Diana] [1541441552] [23] [A]
[Steve Flowers] [1541441553] [21] [A]
[Penny Cooper] [1541441554] [19] [C]
...
```

Instead, I would like to show the data like following

```
[Name]
[ID] [Age] [Group]

[Michael Jones]
[1541441551] [20] [S]

[Emily Diana]
[1541441552] [23] [A]

[Steve Flowers]
[1541441553] [21] [A]
....
```

because this is easier to see, and I wouldn't have to worry about rows getting horizontally extremely long when they get a long name.

How could this be achieved? Or is NOT using `DataGridView` easier (for example, just use `panels` and `labels` for each record, etc)?

Comment: Don't even try to use a DataGridView for this.

Comment: `use panels and labels for each record` thats a lot of controls to create - research `UserControls` and perhaps *pivot queries*

Comment: I don't think the proposed change would be an improvement.  I know my eyes wouldn't enjoy the double-row view of things.

Comment: @LarsTech, the records are colored in turns (gray, white, gray, white ...).

Comment: The result would not be able to be updated, so there's that too

Comment: Looks like you are asking for banded view. The standard `DataGridView` does not support it out of the box, you need some 3rd party UI control suite (DevExpress, Syncfusion etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use a user control as the control of the one and only column of your DataGridView. The user control can then contain name, ID, Age and Group labels in the arrangement you like.

How to use user controls in DataGridViews, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells